# How to print to console in lambda call in Java 8

Tags: java, lambda

I am trying to print to system console within a lambda call, but it does not show in the output window (both within IDE and when run as mvn test)

Here is the code

```
public List<FieldDto> findField(String fieldKey) {
    jdbcTemplate.setQueryTimeout(10);
    System.out.println("\n\n\n\n ----------- seeeee  ----------------------");
    List<FieldDto> result = jdbcTemplate.query("select * from V_FIELD where FIELD_KEY = '" + fieldKey + "'",
            (rs, rowNum) -> getFieldDto(rs, rowNum)
    );
    System.out.println("\n\n\n\n ----------- done  ----------------------");
    return result;

}
```

and the method getFieldDto is defined as

```
private FieldDto getFieldDto(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
    FieldDto fieldDto = new FieldDto();
    System.out.println(" .. in getFieldDto:");
    try {
        fieldDto.FIELD_KEY = rs.getString("FIELD_KEY");
        fieldDto.CREATE_DATE = rs.getString("CREATE_DATE");

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(" exception getFieldDto:" + ex.getMessage());
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
    return fieldDto;
}
```

when I run the jUnit test, the console does show the 
---see--- and ----done---, console logs, but not the '.. in getFieldDto'

why is that not happening, how can I print within the Lambda calls

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference.  Are you sure the method is being called?

Comment: Looks like `jdbcTemplate.query()` is not returning results. Did you try debugging?

Comment: @shmosel  you are right the DB connection is pointing to the wrong env. Therefore no result set. how do I upvote your answer

Comment: First you should do some debugging. Use the IDE debugger to set a breakpoint in the lambda to see if it is executed. If you are still having difficulty, create a [mcve]. You should build this up as a new project and only include the parts that are relevant to illustrate your problem. Often this process will help you find the error yourself. If you still need help, now you have a specific code example to share with us and we will be better able to answer you question.

Comment: Note that your current code example here is far from Complete because there are many compiler errors. You do not have a class and you are missing variable declarations.

Comment: When do you expect the lambda function to be called?

Answer (score 2):

A lambda expression creates an instance of an anonymous inner class with a single method. The method is not called at the time of creation. Instead, it is called at some later point as a callback.

I believe you want to call the method immediately and pass the results as a parameter. So do exactly that! Do not wrap the call in a lambda expression:

```
List<FieldDto> result = jdbcTemplate.query("select * from V_FIELD where FIELD_KEY = '" + fieldKey + "'",
         getFieldDto(rs, rowNum));
```

Additionally, you should be very wary about concatenating strings to create a SQL query. This possibly leaves your app open to a SQL injection attack if you concatenate a String whose value comes from user input. Instead, you should use syntax like `FIELD_KEY = ?` in your query and the appropriate JDBC call which provides the parameters for the `?` placeholder. JDBC will then clean all input to reduce the risk of an attack.